# Bootstrap width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have already read the previous questions/answers about this but i'm still not fully grasping it.

I'm "making" a website for my cousin with a simple div and a list.

Underneath i want the timeline example shown here: https://codepen.io/ksantangelo/pen/ZBOpoJ

If i use the code without the css it works fine, but once i add the css the timeline is shown next to the previous div with my list. The part of the css file causing it is:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I just don't understand why. And what is the easiest way in bootstrap to make sure a section will always be full width?

Comment: Add the code that is problematic

Comment: Purely a guess since you haven't included any HTML, but the problem very well may be that you have included `display: flex`, which by default has `flex-direction: row`, meaning it'll squeeze all the content side-by-side. If you want the timeline to show up below some other div, add `flex-direction: column`. Or, you can add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `body`, and then any combination of widths on the timeline and other div that add up to more than 100% will force the timeline to wrap below the other div.

Comment: @Dekel  the css shown is the problematic bit. Without it works as expected.

Comment: @cjl750 will try this first thing in the morning.